# AWS cloudwatch SNS service dashboard "No metrics available to show"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Although I have SNS metrics available if I want to see metrics on CloudWatch "home page" dashboard. SNS is not showing up, all other service metrics are available.

Is there any catch for SNS?

Comment: Are you checking the correct region and has the SNS topic actually has anything publish to it?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams yes, if I open CLoudWatch metrics, I see my SMS deliveries and other SNS metrics present